# Module import fails only in docker

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, python-import

I'm using a third party packages in my Flask application. When I tested these packages outside of the Flask application and docker, they worked just fine. When I include them in the application, after the docker is built and run it fails on some imports. I cannot find out what should I do to make it import the modules correctly.

This is the structure of the project:

```
flask_app
├── Dockerfile
├── canetis
|   ├── install.sh
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── align.py
|   ├── utils.py
|   ├── gentle
|       ├── install.sh
|       ├── gentle
|           ├── __init__.py
|           ├── resources.py
|           ├── util
|               ├── __init__.py
|               ├── paths.py
|       ├── ext
|           ├── kaldi
|               ├── install.sh
```

The `gentle` package is cloned from git in the `canetis/install.sh` script.

The used dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo

ADD ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /app

RUN cd ./canetis && ./install.sh && source ~/.bashrc

ENV WEB_CONCURRENCY 5

CMD gunicorn app:app
```

When the docker is built, if fails with this error:

```
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
|     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
|     exec code in run_globals
|   File "/app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
|     import tasks
|   File "tasks.py", line 3, in <module>
|     from canetis.align import align
|   File "canetis/align.py", line 3, in <module>
|     from utils import run_gentle
|   File "canetis/utils.py", line 2, in <module>
|     import gentle as gentle
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gentle/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
|     from resources import Resources
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gentle/resources.py", line 4, in <module>
|     from util.paths import get_resource, ENV_VAR
| ImportError: No module named util.paths
```

May the problem be that the gentle module has a subfolder named gentle and so python cannot find it properly? But why does it work outside of docker? Any help appreciated.

Comment: The module you are importing is deep in your folder structure and that is nowhere reflected in your import, also there'a an `__init__.py` missing.

Comment: You mean `canetis/gentle/__init__.py`? It isn't there. I put it all here exactly how it is in the packages. If you're saying it is missing there, how is it possible that the packages work when used without docker?

Comment: So if anyone came to a similar issue, setting the PYTHONPATH env variable in the dockerfile to point the `canetis/gentle/gentle` directory solved the problem.